# Get CGContext errors when displaying uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using a spinning activity indicator for showing progressing when I scroll down the UITableView to
load more results. It should work like this: if I reach the last index of the data array UITableView will display an activity indicator on next cell. However whenever I get rid of the old data array and use a new data array and use `reloadData` the activity indicator doesn't go away. The activity indicator will be in the same cell of another existing data cell. In the debug window it displays some CGContext errors:

```
 <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetTextMatrix: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetFontSize: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetTextPosition: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances: invalid context 0x0
```

How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code at cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
TNSTableViewCell *videoCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"videoCell"];

if (videoCell == nil) {
    videoCell = [[TNSTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"videoCell"];
}

// When scroll down last index of the index load next page
if (indexPath.row >= self.entries.count) {
    if (!loading) {
        NSLog(@"Loading new records...");
        loading = YES;

        if (fetchBatch != 0) {
            [informationDownloader getSearchRecordsWithKeywords:nil];
        }

    }
}

if (indexPath.row < self.entries.count) {

if (videoCell.activityIndicator) {
    videoCell.activityIndicator = nil;
}
TNSVideoRecord *record = [self.entries objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

videoCell.textLabel.text = record.title;
videoCell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
videoCell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
videoCell.detailTextLabel.text = [@"views: " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n%@", [record.viewCount stringValue], record.uploader];
videoCell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

if (!record.image) {
    if (self.thumbnailVideoTableView.dragging == NO && self.thumbnailVideoTableView.decelerating == NO) {

        [informationDownloader downloadThumbnailForRecord:record];
    }
    // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image
    UIImageView *imageView = videoCell.imageView;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    indicator.alpha = 1.0;
    indicator.center = imageView.center;
    [imageView addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator startAnimating];
} else {
    videoCell.imageView.image = record.image;
}

videoCell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
videoCell.imageView.tag = [indexPath row];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(playVideo:)];
[videoCell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

UIImage *playButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playbutton.png"];

NSString *durationText = [TNSUtilities convertDuration:record.length];
UIImage *image = [TNSUtilities drawText:durationText inImage:[TNSUtilities drawImage:playButtonImage inImage:videoCell.imageView.image]];
videoCell.imageView.image = image;

videoCell.accessoryView.tag = [indexPath row];
videoCell.accessoryView = [self makeAddButton];
videoCell.accessoryView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[videoCell setNeedsLayout];

} else {
    NSLog(@"Displaying spinning indicator.");
    videoCell.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    videoCell.activityIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [videoCell addSubview:videoCell.activityIndicator];
    videoCell.activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 15, videoCell.frame.size.height/2 - 15, 30, 30);
    videoCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [videoCell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [videoCell setNeedsLayout];

}

return videoCell;
```

As you can see there is also another activity indicator in the imageView and that indicator also remains on the imageView after I update my data array. Strangely the indicator doesn't appear on every uitableviewcell.

Here is my implementation of prepareReuse in TNSTableViewCell which is a subclass of UITableViewCell:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    if (self.activityIndicator) {
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        self.activityIndicator = nil;
    }

    self.textLabel.text = nil;
    self.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
}
```

Here is the drawText method and drawImage method:

```
+ (UIImage *)drawText:(NSString *)text inImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGRect bgRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [image drawInRect: bgRect];

    CGFloat rectWidth;

    if (text.length < 6) {
        rectWidth = 40.0f;
    } else {
        rectWidth = 56.0f;
    }

    CGRect textRect = CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(0, 0, rectWidth, 14), bgRect.size.width - rectWidth, bgRect.size.height - 14);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 100.0f/255.0f, 100.0f/255.0f, 100.0f/255.0f, 1.0f);
    CGContextFillRect(context, textRect);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    [text drawInRect:textRect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}

+ (UIImage *)drawImage:(UIImage *)fgImage inImage:(UIImage *)bgImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bgImage.size, FALSE, 0.0);
    CGRect bgRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, bgImage.size.width, bgImage.size.height);
    [bgImage drawInRect:bgRect];
    [fgImage drawInRect:CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(0, 0, fgImage.size.width, fgImage.size.height), bgRect.size.width/2 - fgImage.size.width/2, bgRect.size.height/2 - fgImage.size.height/2)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: Do you have any code that uses those functions? Also make sure all of your UI updates are being done on the main thread. If you are doing some asynchronous data fetches, make sure when you get the results, you update the UI on the main thread.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint on `CGPostError` to see exactly where those messages are being logged. But I doubt it will help.  Just in case, though, you can dump the stack trace in the debugger console using the `bt` command, copy it, and paste it into your question.

Comment: To create a breakpoint on `CGPostError`, choose Product > Debug > Create Symbolic Breakpoint from the menu bar, and enter `CGPostError` as the symbol.

Comment: UIImage *image = [TNSUtilities drawText:durationText inImage:[TNSUtilities drawImage:playButtonImage inImage:videoCell.imageView.image]];

put code of drawText method

Answer (score 0):

When you reuse a cell and add a subview, it stays there. So next time you reuse it you need to check if there is a subview and explicitly relive it.

For your activity indicator, when the cell is removed from display but the indicator is still animating it will be trying to draw without a valid context.

Try stopping / removing the indicator both when the cell goes off screen and is reused. Or, consider simplifying your cell setup and using a footer view to hold the activity indicator and just remove the footer when done.